# How to make CMake not ignore include paths with . (dots) to find home brew packages

Tags: cmake, homebrew

For a C++ project I'm trying to add a include path which contains all the headers for third party includes like boost, ssl, zgip etc.
I'm using Homebrew as package manager, so it has installed everything in
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew`
and the include path is
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include`
Of course this include directory contains symlinks to all headers.

When I try to add this directory using

```
set(SYSTEM_INCLUDES "$ENV{INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("Using system includes as : ${SYSTEM_INCLUDES}")
target_include_directories(app PRIVATE ${SYSTEM_INCLUDES})
```

CMake just ignores this path.
Verified that it can see the path, but doesn't add it to the command or to the compile_command.json.

System :
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on WSL2 (Win11)
CMake :  3.28.2

What I've tried:
Create a symlink without a '.' in the path, and use that path, same behavior.
Mount the directory somewhere, doesn't work as the symlinks in the include directory have relative paths.

I've tried to look for answers online, no luck.

Comment: Just checked: CMake doesn't ignore paths with dot-prefixed components. Probably, CMake treats `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include` as system include directory ([CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH.html)) which is added automatically by the compiler. Please, prepare [mcve] and show output of CMake.